# when the user upload a new image the previous image delete from folder laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image

when the user upload new image i want to delete the previous image in folder i use Laravel....i try to make some things but not work for me any ideas?

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
File::delete($user->pic);
```

---

```
#profileController
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function index($slug){
        return view('profile.index')->with('data', Auth::user()->profile);
    }

    public function uploadPhoto(Request $request) {
        $file = $request->file('pic');
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $path = 'storage/img';

        $file->move($path, $filename);
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

        DB::table('users')->where('id',$user_id)->update(['pic' =>$filename]);

        return redirect('/editProfile')->withSuccess('Your image was successful.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$idname = User::where('user_id', $request->userid)->update([
    'users_profile_name' => $usersName
]);
File::delete('/public/uploads/users/".$request->userid."');

$file=$request->file('users_profile_name');
$file->move(base_path('/public/uploads/users'),$usersName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) function of php,

```
unlink($file_path);
```

To create Path :

```
$file_path = base_path().'/images/post/'.$post->photo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using unlink() function. Here's the code from my project that deletes the previous picture if the user wants to add another:

```
$usersImage = public_path("/images/{$user->photo->path}"); //Finding users previous picture
        if(file_exists($usersImage)){ //If it exits, delete it from folder
            unlink($usersImage);
        }
```

After that you just add your logic for adding another picture